# Uploading files directly to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload the file to s3 server, using s3_direct_upload gem. I have followed the instruction in document. But I am unable to upload the file. I am getting following error:

```
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
```

My bucket region is **us-east-2**.

And following is my initializer content:

```
S3DirectUpload.config do |c|
  c.access_key_id     = ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
  c.secret_access_key = ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
  c.bucket            = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]
  c.region            = ENV["AWS_REGION"]
  c.url               = "https://#{ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com" 
end
```

Comment: I think you have to add `s3_signature_version: :v4` into config. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27847888/2681997.

Comment: @AjayBarot thanks for the reply. But i am bit confused where to write this line: `s3_signature_version: :v4`. Could you please guide me here?

Comment: Are you using which gem for file upload  paperclip or carrierwave ?

Comment: @AjayBarot I am using paperclip

Comment: Add s3_signature_version: :v4 into AWS.config. Ref: follow this link. http://www.connp.com/ror/2014/01/02/integrate-s3_direct_upload-with-paperclip-in-rails-application/

Comment: @AjayBarot That didn't helped :(